# Size of image stream in opencv for Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

In Python 3.7 I read an png image with opencv and convert it to an jpg image stream. How can I determine the number of bytes of the stream?

```
image=cv2.imread('test.png',0)
image_stream = io.BytesIO(cv2.imencode(".jpg",image)[1].tobytes())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(success, data) = cv2.imencode(".jpg", image)
assert success
print(data.nbytes)
```

This number of bytes is identical to the size of the `bytes` object returned by the `.tobytes()` call. Creating a `BytesIO()` also does not affect this size.

Comment: yes. `tobytes()` doesn't change it (array dtype is uint8), and neither does the `BytesIO` constructor